# Should we re-ask questions that were asked on other sites?

Tags: discussion

I've asked signal processing related questions on other sites before this one existed.  Should I re-ask them here? Should I flag them to be migrated?  Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120422/is-there-an-fft-that-uses-a-logarithmic-division-of-frequency
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141342/identifying-common-periodic-waveforms-square-sine-sawtooth
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787536/which-time-frequency-coefficients-does-the-wavelet-transform-compute
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43084/whats-the-difference-between-the-gabor-and-morlet-wavelets

Comment: In a similar vein, it would be useful to be able to close and migrate all future questions about FFT, pitch detection, filtering, etc from stackoverflow.com to dsp.stackexchange.com once it's live. Is that going to be possible ?

Comment: @PaulR: Assuming those questions all belong here.  There is a lot of overlap and we need to decide where to put things.

Comment: @Paul - Only if those questions are off-topic on the sites that they're asked on.  We should definitely monitor those tags, and suggest "Hey, you might get a better answer on DSP" in comments.  However, they're still on topic for those sites, and should probably not get migrated unless the OP asks for it.

Comment: Good point Kevin! Only if they're off-topic on their own sites.

Comment: @Kevin: it would be good to have some sort of criteria for deciding whether a DSP-related question belongs on SO or DSP, e.g. for FFT questions maybe if it's general theory then it's DSP but if it's a language-specific implementation then it belongs on SO ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we want to ask people to NOT re-ask questions. If they are an *extremely* good match for signals.se, then we can flag them and ask them to be migrated (let's get out of the private beta first) and if they're just *ok* questions then we want to wait until later in the public beta to migrate them (or invite their OP to re-ask them here).

If the other question *is already answered* then forget about it till later (like at least 30 days from now)

Comment: If they're an extremely good match for DSP, why not just ask them here?

Comment: Because of the migration mechanism. That's really the main thing. Make sure that each Q lives on one home. As for why not to migrate too early, the site may not actually live long enough.

Answer (score 1):

On top of jcolebrands answer I'd like to point out that there are countless problems to be solved that have not yet been asked on Stack Overflow or Cross Validated (to a lesser degree).

So instead of looking jealously to the questions they already have and might get in the future, we should focus on asking interesting questions that would entice these users to start asking or answering questions here as well when the private beta is over

Comment: It's not about jealousy, it's about more specialized users providing better answers than the questions previously had

Comment: It wasn't meant to call you out specifically, but there are some questions on SO that make me think "geeh, it would have been great to have something like this on DSP"

Comment: then it should be migrated to where it belongs :)